# How to check correctly for (const) overloaded method

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I am currently trying to get the following to compile:

```
class foo {
};

class bar {
public:
  const foo & to_foo() const {
    return f;
  }

  foo & to_foo() {
    return f;
  }
private:
 foo f;
};

template< typename T, typename Enable = void >
class convert {};

template< typename T >
struct convert< T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_member_function_pointer< decltype( &T::to_foo ) >::value >::type > {

  static const foo & call1( const bar & b ) {
    return b.to_foo();
  }

  static foo & call2( bar & b ) {
    return b.to_foo();
  }
};
```

However the specialisation get's confused by the presence of two possible `to_foo()` members, so it will choose the default case. As soon as I remove one of the `to_foo()` members, it works, but then one of the `callX()` methods fails because it does not match the constness.

Is there any way to detect this function in this case?

**EDIT**:

Here is an example on ideone: http://ideone.com/E6saX

When one of the the methods is removed, it works just fine: http://ideone.com/iBKoN

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve here. It would be better if you could illustrate the use of `convert` so that we can see what you are trying to achieve instead of getting lost in the particulars of your current attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: This is part of a much more complicated larger framework, which handles multiple types. For some types a conversion is necessary, before they can be used. However I need a way to detect how to convert from and to these converted types as this is highly dependent on the input type. The given code is a small destilled down portion of this, that I am currently trying to get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still a bit unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. I will suppose that the target type (`foo`) is fixed and we are not attempting to create a full bridge system.

In this case, we can ditch the structure and just rely on overload selection.

```
foo const& to_foo(bar const& b) { return b.to_foo(); }
foo& to_foo(bar& b) { return b.to_foo(); }
```

Works just fine, as far as the actual translation goes. No template involved.

Now the question might be how to actually *detect* whether this conversion is possible or not. In this case, we need to use SFINAE to avoid a hard-error while attempting the conversion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

// Didn't remember where this is implemented, oh well
template <typename T, typename U> struct same_type: std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct same_type<T, T>: std::true_type {};

// Types to play with
struct Foo {};
struct Bar { Foo _foo; };
struct Bad {};

Foo const& to_foo(Bar const& b) { return b._foo; }
Foo& to_foo(Bar& b) { return b._foo; }

// Checker
template <typename T>
struct ToFoo {
  T const& _crt;
  T& _rt;

  template <typename U>
  static auto to_foo_exists(U const& crt, U& rt) ->
      decltype(to_foo(crt), to_foo(rt), std::true_type());

  static std::false_type to_foo_exists(...);

  // Work around as the following does not seem to work
  // static bool const value = decltype(to_foo_exists(_crt, _rt))::value;
  static bool const value = same_type<
                                decltype(to_foo_exists(_crt, _rt)),
                                std::true_type
                            >::value;
};

// Proof
int main() {
  std::cout << ToFoo<Bar>::value << "\n"; // true
  std::cout << ToFoo<Bad>::value << "\n"; // false
}
```

Note: successfully compiled on Clang 3.0 (with the work around) and [gcc 4.5.1](http://ideone.com/CHJM0).

Comment: Ah, I see. The extra indirection helpes in the case where I get errors. For now I just fixed this problem by forcing one method to be renamed from `to_foo()` to `to_const_foo()`. However this is more of a ugly hack, because the two methods really do the same thing, so they should have the same name. I'll see if I can adopt your method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about templates yet, but it seems that `is_const` is the type trait you're looking for, to check as to whether the function is `const`.

Link [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const)

Comment: The difficulty though is that `T::to_foo` cannot be deduced because the method is overloaded. For overloaded methods a `static_cast` to the correct signature is required.

Comment: No, `is_const` is clearly not helping, since I am just trying to figure out if the method exists at all. I do not really care about the const except in the later parts. I might have to split the `convert` class later into parts that handle constness and non-constness, but this does not solve the problem of detecting the presence of the overloaded method.

Answer (score -1):

my gcc(4.1.0) is not support c++0x, so i remove the std::enable_if part. then it compiles and runs successfullly.
see: 
http://ideone.com/KzasX

thanks